# Do i have to prefer ajax pagination?

Tags: web, pagination

I am currently using classic pagination and the thing which i found annoying is we are doing whole page process for only second partial pagination.So i would earn performance benefit for pagination with ajax without including layout contents also it is better by user perspective.

But i want to know that is there any downside of this? None ajax pagination is better for SEO optimizations ? Do  you i have to prefer post or get method for SEO?

What is your suggestions about pagination ajax and none ajax ?

If ajax pagination is better so why stackoverflow doesn't use it in main pages ?

Answer (score 2):

The performance benefit achieved but not rendering your layout component(s) is going to be marginal. And it's much better for SEO. And all pagination links should be GET.

**Edit:**It's also much better for bookmarkable urls.